# How To Call a page using button in Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class Menu1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static Button button_sbm;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
       /* return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_1, container, false);*/
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_1, container, false);
        button_sbm = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Home");
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainWeb.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

How To Intent To MainWeb Class..

This My XML

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/yoga"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="Goto Website"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Fragment to Activity
What to do?

When I click the button, it gives me a message

> "Unfortantly App Was Stopped"

Comment: What is MainWeb.class ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **MainWeb** Activity class is mentioned in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

**Don't create a static instances** of Button or any UI widget in your fragment or Activity. That may lead to memory leak.